# Compositing a back plate so the mist pass does not affect it

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am rendering a city scene and I am using the mist pass to give a sense of depth and distance. I am using an image for the back plate background image. How can I alter my node setup below to stop the mist pass affecting the back plate. Thank you.

[image: render where the backplate is misted out!]

[image: node setup]

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Mist that only erases objects and not background?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26721/mist-that-only-erases-objects-and-not-background/26734#26734)

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67832/mist-dof-alpha-in-cycles/67939#67939

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69235/how-to-lose-colour-on-distant-objects/69274#69274